# Subtypes of Arrays

Tags: java

If I have `class A {` and `class B extends A {` will

```
B[] b = new B[1];
b[0] = new B();
System.out.println(b instanceof A[]);
```

print out true or false?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You don't have access to a Java compiler or something?

Comment: Silly me. Too lazy to create a new main class =(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2-320) that if B is assignable to A, then yes, B[] is assignable to A[].

This opens the door to serious implications though, demonstrated by this code:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

//...
B[] bs = new B[2];
A[] as = bs;
as[0] = new C(); //runtime error
B b = bs[0];
```

This code [compiles but fails at runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.5).  We call that a lack of type safety.

Answer (score 1):

```
// A.java
public class A {}

// B.java
public class B extends A {}

// Test.java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B[] b = new B[1];
        b[0] = new B();
        System.out.println(b instanceof A[]);
    }
}
```

When run:

```
> javac *.java && java Test
true
```

Answer (score 0):

It will print `true`.

Answer (score -4):

false.

Arrays don't follow the same rules as normal Objects.

Comment: Well, you had a 50/50 chance, sorry it didn't work out for you.

Comment: You probably mistook arrays with generics.

Comment: I remembered the type safety implications, and misremembered how it was handled.